# Adding source and target fields in attribute table

Tags: qgis, export, csv

My issue is I want to export a CSV-file from QGIS 3.6.2 to Gephi (network analysis software) the layer I want to export is the edges layer for Gephi. However, when importing into Gephi I am missing the `"source"` and `"target"` fields in the CSV file.

More specific I have a layer `'trails'` with thousand of features on it and want to see which water hole they go to are they connected? but I don't know what the next step is.

Comment: Which QGIS version is that? How did you accomplish the export from QGIS of your csv-file?

Comment: You need to make nodes, I use plugin AequilibraE. This plugin makes the source and target fields.

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.6.2.... I can't seem to find the plugin AequilibraE but I have looked at it doesn't seem to have been updated to QGIS 3

Comment: What if you build startpoints and endpoints of your trails and use these points as source and target? Not sure how your data looks like, but basically this should work.

Comment: I used the Qchainage plugin to create the start and end points. however all start points are 0 is this right? and the end points are how long it is from the start point in meters. I was aiming for more of a latitude and longitude of each point so I could use the geolayout installer in Gephi